# Laplace’s equation on the circular zone

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, partial-differential-equations

Consider the Laplace’s equation in the circular zone:
$$\frac{\partial^2u}{\partial{x^2}}+\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial{y^2}}=0, $$
where $(r,\theta)\in \mathbb{R}^2$ and $u(a,\theta)=b\cos^2\theta$. The center of the circular zone is the origin, radius $a$, and $b$ is a constant.

i) Solve the Dirichlet Problem  in the circular zone?

ii) When does a solution exists ?

iii) Solve the boundary-value problem?

I am aware of that I can' t write anything about my solution attempt because I don't have any ideas.

Comment: Should the radius be $a$?

Comment: Yes, radius is $a$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*HINT:* Write the solution as

$$
u(r,\theta) = R(r)\Theta(\theta)
$$

and replace it in the equation

$$
\frac{1}{r}\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left(r \frac{\partial u}{\partial r}\right) + \frac{1}{r^2}\frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial\theta^2} = 0
$$

Separate the $R$s on one side, and the $\Theta$s on the other. Solve equation separately and apply the boundary conditions

Comment: BTW.. is it also not the  stress function or buharmonic eqaution in polar coordinates (mechanics)?